# Read file elements into array and use as html form elements

Tags: php, arrays, file, text

Hi guys I have been trying to do this for sometime. Would you please give me an insight on how to go about this. 
I have a text file containing questions and their respective multiple choice answer spaced using space bar between each element. 
I have been able to read and put the text file lines into arrays. But now what has prooved difficult to achieve is how to put each and every element to an html form element. these are my codes:

Text file:

Number  Question    (a) (b) (c) (d)
1   The most important feature of spiral model is requirement analysis.     risk management.     quality management.    configuration management.
2   The worst type of coupling is    Data coupling.     control coupling.   stamp coupling.     content coupling.
3   One of the fault base testing techniques is     unit testing.   beta testing.   Stress testing.     mutation testing.
4   A fault simulation testing technique is  Mutation testing   Stress testing  Black box testing   White box testing
5   RS is also known as specification of    White box testing   Stress testing  Integrated testing  Black box testing

The page that reads the text file:

```
`html>
<head>
<title>read</title>
</head>
<body>
<b><u> QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS QUIZ</u></b <br /> 
<p>
<?php
$openFile = fopen("questionandanswers.txt", "r") or exit ("unable to open the text       file");
$fileContents = fread($openFile, filesize("questionandanswers.txt"));
fclose($openFile);
$delimiter = "  ";
$myArray = explode($delimiter, $fileContents);
print_r($myArray);
?>
</p>
</body>
</html>`
```

THe print_r displays the following:

Array ( [0] => Number [1] => Question [2] => (a) [3] => (b) [4] => (c) [5] => (d) 1 [6] => The most important feature of spiral model is requirement analysis. [7] => risk management. [8] => quality management. [9] => configuration management. 2 [10] => The worst type of coupling is [11] => Data coupling. [12] => control coupling. [13] => stamp coupling. [14] => content coupling. 3 [15] => One of the fault base testing techniques is [16] => unit testing. [17] => beta testing. [18] => Stress testing. [19] => mutation testing. 4 [20] => A fault simulation testing technique is [21] => Mutation testing [22] => Stress testing [23] => Black box testing [24] => White box testing 5 [25] => RS is also known as specification of [26] => White box testing [27] => Stress testing [28] => Integrated testing [29] => Black box testing )

Comment: can you post what you get in print_r($myArray)

Comment: When i print_r i get the following. I have added it as part of the question

Comment: what following friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `explode()` using space as separator, that's why you are getting each word as an array element. `explode()` just uses the character you give it and split the string whenever it encounters the character.

Your data (the file) hasn't got a pattern. So you need to stablish some rules in the text, or you won't be able to separate the information you want:

I modified your text stablishing some rules:

1. The questions will be finished with a colon(:).
2. The answers will be finished with a dot(.), all of them but the last one, as we will use the number of the question as separator.
3. The questions or answers won't contain any numbers [0-9] or it will confuse the regex.

This is the resulting text I modified manually to make the text work:

```
$string = 'Number Question (a) (b) (c) (d) 1 The most important feature of spiral model is: requirement analysis. risk management. quality management. configuration management 2 The worst type of coupling is: Data coupling. control coupling. stamp coupling. content coupling 3 One of the fault base testing techniques is: unit testing. beta testing. Stress testing. mutation testing 4 A fault simulation testing technique is: Mutation testing. Stress testing. Black box testing. White box testing 5 RS is also known as: specification of White box testing. Stress testing. Integrated testing. Black box testing';
```

---

The solution:
After that we can use some code to separate the information:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>read</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <b><u> QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS QUIZ</u></b> <br />
<?php
$openFile = fopen("questionandanswers.txt", "r") or exit ("unable to open the text       file");
$string = fread($openFile, filesize("questionandanswers.txt"));

//Regex to get from the first number to the string's end, so we ignore the Number Question... bit;
preg_match('/\d.*/', $string, $match);

//We get all the strings starting with a number until it finds another number (which will be the beginning of another question;
preg_match_all('/\d\D*/', $match[0], $results);

$qas = array(); // We prepare an array with all the questions/answers
foreach($results[0] as $result){
    //Separating the answer from the string with all the answers.
    list($question, $all_answers) = explode(':', $result);

    //Separating the different answers
    $answers_array = explode('.', $all_answers);

    //Stuffing the question and the array with all the answers into the previously prepared array;
    $qas[] = array('question' => $question, 'answers' => $answers_array);
}

//Looping through the array and outputting all the info into a form;
foreach($qas as $k => $v){
    echo "<label>{$v['question']}</label><br/>";
    echo "<select>";

    //we loop through $v['answers'] because its an array within the array with all the answers.
    foreach($v['answers'] as $answer){
        echo "<option>$answer</option>";//the output
    }
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<br/><br/>";
}

?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Looks complex because of all the comments, they are less than 20 lines of text actually

You can see the output here: [output](http://aleation.com/test3.php)

---

**Notes**
Did this just to practice, but next time try to research more, and ask specific questions, or people will ignore/downvote your, have a good read about the Stackoverflow's FAQs

Comment: Thanks a lot friend. I want to learn how you did this. in your coding where does it join the previous codes that I had?

Comment: I know as an amateur we at times become a bother, but how do i use th above codes to submit as a  form to a php file processor to process the same. Thanks a lot friend.

Comment: I have edited the code to give you a clue how to join it. Use $string instead of $fileContent. About the forms, that's very basic, but I won't write a full tutorial here about forms, google a bit and learn to do it, while you encounter specific problems as here at Stackoverflow

Comment: Just putting the above codes in a format  can be submitted to a Php file e.g upon submission I can use the $_POST method to validate the posted values. Thanks once again.

Comment: How do i put it into a form e.g. <form action="processor.php" value="submit"><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" /></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>

Comment: You need to put it into a text input or textarea

Comment: I have been trying to put the arrays into text formats. Would please assist. You can look at the codes and see how I have been trying to go about it. Thank you.

Comment: The edit suggest has been reject by various users and they are right, it would change totally the question/answer therefore breaking the workflow of stackoverflow, please use your new code with the newly prepared information and open a new answer, having the forms as the new subject instead of the file reading.

Answer (score 0):

You should format your array into a multidimensional one, where the index 0 is the question:

```
Array
(
    [0] = array
    (
        [0] = "This is the first question";
        [1] = "Answer A";
        [2] = "Answer B";
    )
    [1] = array
    (
        [0] = "This is the second question";
        [1] = "Answer A";
        [2] = "Answer B";
        [3] = "Answer C";
    )
)
```

You can now include it the following way:

```
<form>
    <?php
        foreach($filecontent as $question)
        {
            echo '<p>' .$question[0] .'</p>';
            for($i = 1; $i < count($question); $i++)
            {
                echo '<input value="' .$question[$i] .'" />';
            }
        }
    ?>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm still not well conversant with using multidimensional arrays, would you please give me an insight on how to go about it using my codes please. thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Especially from the point $myArray = explode($delimiter, $fileContents);
print_r($myArray);
?>
</p>
</body>
</html>`